# AWS LAMBDA - MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am trying to create automatic sound through elevenlabs, add the sound I created to the beginning of the video and publish it.

this is my lambda_function.py file

```
import json
import boto3
import uuid
import requests
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeAudioClip, AudioFileClip
os.environ['TMPDIR'] = '/tmp'

def text_to_speech_with_elevenlabs(text, api_key):
    url = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/Lx6D7XYCyKMECIXTTYg2"
    payload = {
        "model_id": "eleven_multilingual_v2",
        "text": text,
        "voice_settings": {
            "stability": 0.5,
            "similarity_boost": 0.75,
            "style": 0,
            "clarity": 0.75
        }
    }
    headers = {
        "xi-api-key": api_key,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    # Ses dosyasını doğrudan indir
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, stream=True)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.content
    else:
        raise Exception(f"ElevenLabs API request failed: {response.status_code} {response.text}")

def download_audio(audio_content, filename):
    # Ses içeriğini dosyaya yaz
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(audio_content)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    api_key = "x"
    bucket_name = "video-projects-t"
    unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    first_name = event['first_name']
    last_name = event['last_name']
    text = f"some words bla bla, {first_name} {last_name}."

    audio_content = text_to_speech_with_elevenlabs(text, api_key)
    tts_audio_path = f"/tmp/{unique_id}_tts.mp3"
    download_audio(audio_content, tts_audio_path)

    original_video_key = "Video2.mp4"
    original_video_path = f"/tmp/{unique_id}_original.mp4"
    output_video_path = f"/tmp/{unique_id}_processed_video.mp4"
    upload_key = f"/tmp/{unique_id}_processed_video.mp4"

    s3.download_file(bucket_name, original_video_key, original_video_path)

    video_clip = VideoFileClip(original_video_path)
    tts_audio_clip = AudioFileClip(tts_audio_path)
    final_audio = CompositeAudioClip([video_clip.audio, tts_audio_clip.set_start(0)])
    final_video = video_clip.set_audio(final_audio)
    final_video.write_videofile(output_video_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")

    s3.upload_file(output_video_path, bucket_name, upload_key)

    video_url = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{upload_key}"

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f"{video_url}")
    }
```

My LAMBDA Error logs here:

```
Moviepy - Building video /tmp/0d5cae91-76d9-4fb3-9299-f8e6a0bbb056_processed_video.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in 0d5cae91-76d9-4fb3-9299-f8e6a0bbb056_processed_videoTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file 0d5cae91-76d9-4fb3-9299-f8e6a0bbb056_processed_videoTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4:

b'0d5cae91-76d9-4fb3-9299-f8e6a0bbb056_processed_videoTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4: Read-only file system\n'

In case it helps, make sure you are using a recent version of FFMPEG (the versions in the Ubuntu/Debian repos are deprecated).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 64, in lambda_handler
    final_video.write_videofile(output_video_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
  File "<decorator-gen-55>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-54>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 135, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-53>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/var/task/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 293, in write_videofile
    self.audio.write_audiofile(audiofile, audio_fps,
  File "<decorator-gen-45>", line 2, in write_audiofile
  File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/var/task/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 206, in write_audiofile
    return ffmpeg_audiowrite(self, filename, fps, nbytes, buffersize,
  File "<decorator-gen-9>", line 2, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
  File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/var/task/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 170, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
    writer.write_frames(chunk)
  File "/var/task/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 117, in write_frames
    raise IOError(error)END RequestId: bb60b756-5da7-4cd6-9979-d227ed8fd6e0
```

I am trying to create automatic sound through elevenlabs, add the sound I created to the beginning of the video and publish it.

Comment: You can only write to /tmp (or a mounted EFS volume). And note that /tmp has limited diskspace (512 MB by default, though can be expanded).

Comment: You need to add some debugging to understand why the video is being correctly written to `/tmp` but not the audio.  It's going to `0d5cae91-76d9-4fb3-9299-f8e6a0bbb056_processed_videoTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4` which you're not allowed to write to.